# grep tab and star character

Tags: grep

How can I grep for a combination of tab and star (`*`) characters in a text file?

For example:

Input:

```
text    *    0    *    0    *    *    some_text
text    *    9    45   9    0    0    some_text
TEXT    *    0    *    0    0    *    some_text
```

I need to grep for a specific combination of tab and star and zeros, say for example:

```
*    0    *    0    0    *
```

Expected output:

```
TEXT    *    0    *    0    0    *    some_text
```

I can grep for stars, separately, using:

```
grep -P '\t' input > output
```

I can grep for tabs, separately, using:

```
grep '\*' input > output
```

But how can I combine both? I'm trying, unsuccessfully, the following combination:

```
grep -P '\*\t0\t\*0\t0\*' input > output
```

Comment: You're missing a couple of tabs in `'\*\t0\t\*0\t0\*'`: in the middle there's a `*0`, and in the end a `0*`. `grep -P '\*\t0\t\*\t0\t0'` might work.

Comment: oh this was incredibly noobish

Comment: Though it might be helpful to build a pattern like that from an array or something, a Perl solution that comes in mind would be `perl -ne '$pat = join "\t", qw/* 0 * 0 0 */; print if /\Q$pat/'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Portably:

```
tab=$(printf '\t')
grep -F "*${tab}0${tab}*${tab}0${tab}0"
```

With some shells (`ksh93`, `zsh`, `bash`, `mksh`, FreeBSD `sh`), you can use:

```
grep -F $'*\t0\t*\t0\t0'
```

(`$'\t'` can also be written `$'\u0009'` or (on ASCII-based systems) `$'\x09'`, `$'\11'` or `$'\CI'`)

Some `grep` implementations like ast-open's one recognise `\t` (or `\x09`) themselves as meaning a tab character. So you can do:

```
grep '\*\t0\t\*\t0\t0'
```

(same with other regexp types there (`-E` for ERE, `-P` for perl-like (similar to PCRE), `-A` for augmented).

GNU `grep` (at least on GNU systems) doesn't recognise `\t` nor `\x09` with BRE or ERE, but does with PCREs (when the support has been built-in), (and also `\x09` or `\11`).

```
grep -P '\*\t0\t\*\t0\t0'
```

would work with GNU `grep` as long as PCRE support has been enabled (which tends to be the case on modern systems).

Another portable solution is to use `awk` instead were the `\t` is universally supported:

```
awk '/\*\t0\t\*\t0\t0/'
```

Answer (score 1):

According to `ilkkachu` comment:

> Because there are missing a couple of tabs in '*\t0\t*0\t0*': in the middle there's a *0, and in the end a 0*.

The command:

```
grep -P '\*\t0\t\*\t0\t0'
```

will solve that issue.